# Error : method displayOldestAge(List<Player>)

Tags: java

I am learning in OOP Java, I am stuck when I want to call my displayOldestAge() method which is into the class `Player` towards my main file.

I have a class named `Player` with the displayOldestAge() method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Player {

  public String name;
  public int age;
  public boolean sex;


  public Player(String name, int age, boolean sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
  }

  public void display(int number){
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    System.out.println("Number : " + number);
    System.out.println("Name : " + name);
    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("Sex : " + sex);

  }

  public static void displayOldestAge(List<Player> players){

        if (players.size() == 0) return;

        Player oldestPlayer = players.get(0);

        for (Player player : players){
            if (player.age > oldestPlayer.age){
                oldestPlayer = player;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The player oldest age is " + oldestPlayer.name + ", Age: " + oldestPlayer.age);
    }

}
```

But, when I want to call this method towards the file main, I have an error message:

```
Main.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    displayOldestAge(players);
    ^
  symbol:   method displayOldestAge(List<Player>)
  location: class Main
1 error
```

In my Main file I have this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Player> players = new ArrayList <Player>();
    players.add(new Player("Eric", 31, true));

    displayOldestAge(players); 
    
  }
  
}
```

I don't understand ? My method isn't called correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

displayOldestAge function is static function.
And this function is not member function of Main class.
So you have to call like this.

```
Player.displayOldestAge(players)
```

Comment: Hi @eric, if you have any problem in learning Java, please email me. wizard.work@pm.me